# How to line wrap a statement that uses a "true_value if condition else false_value" syntax

Tags: python, word-wrap

I want to wrap this next single line of Python code to < 80 char in accordance with PEP 8.

```
self.settings["bid"]["soloslim_plays_first"] = "True" if settings_pane.check_soloslim_plays_first.isChecked() else "False"
```

This line does not have any parenthesis, so this is what I came up with:

```
self.settings["deal"]["dealer_can_shuffle"] = "True" \
        if settings_pane.check_dealer_shuffle.isChecked() \
        else "False"
```

I don't really like this because true-value & false-value aren't aligned. Is there a better way of wrapping it (e.g. without the backslashes)? I prefer my verbose variable object names, so please don't suggest replacing `check_soloslim_plays_first` by `cspf` ;-)

Comment: You can add parentheses.

Comment: `PEP <80` is from the time we had small monitors, on a 4K monitor no problem with long lines

Comment: You might just want to use ``black`` to auto-format the code for you. It will use a canonical folding instead of just any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add parentheses, around the contents of the `if` statement, then you can format it like this:

```py
self.settings["bid"]["soloslim_plays_first"] = "True" if (
    settings_pane.check_soloslim_plays_first.isChecked()) else "False"
```

Another option is to wrap the whole conditional expression in parantheses:

```py
self.settings["bid"]["soloslim_plays_first"] = (
    "True" if settings_pane.check_soloslim_plays_first.isChecked()
    else "False")
```

Comment: It's a conditional expression, not an if-else statement.